# Are there any animal species other than humans & chimps that engage in tribal conflicts?

Tags: ethology, behaviour

i.e., between tribes within the specie.

(For chimps, see, e.g., https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/01/160130-animals-insects-ants-war-chimpanzees-science.)

Am seeking examples to develop taxonomy of such conflicts, e.g., for resource acquisition, enslavement, etc.

Comment: this depends largely on how you define tribal conflict, ants for instance go to war.

Comment: Thx — elaborated q to clarify

Comment: That does not help clarify. You need to define "tribal conflict" otherwise this is just opinion.

Answer (score 6):

In the introduction of [an article by Gavrilets and Fortunato](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms4526), the authors give (with references) some examples of intra-specific group conflicts:

> Social organisms living in stable groups often engage in aggressive interactions with conspecifics from neighbouring groups over territory, mating opportunities and other resources... Examples include border patrols in chimpanzees, raiding parties in spider monkeys, clan wars in hyenas and between-group fights in lions, free-ranging dogs, meerkats, Capuchin monkeys, blue monkeys, black howler monkeys and ring-tail lemurs.

Whether these conflicts (or others, such as ant colony conflicts) meet your definition of "tribal conflicts" you will have to decide.

Comment: Thank you -very- much — an excellent article, on point.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, bonobos do. A study from [researchers from the Max-Planck Institute for Evolutionary Anthropology back in 2008](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-bonobos-hunting/hippie-apes-make-war-as-well-as-love-study-finds-idUSTRE49C66C20081013) and other research found that even though bonobos prefer to solve problems using sex, [bonobos fight each other](http://www.animalcognition.org/2016/07/31/bonobos-make-love-and-war/) and [even other great apes](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/3353342/Bonobos-not-all-peace-and-free-love.html).

The same thing applies to bees. [Australia's stingless bees go to war](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/11/141110-bees-warfare-hives-australia-insects-animals-science/#close) where thousands of [worker bees perish and the young from the losing side are dragged out of the nest to die](http://www.zoo.ox.ac.uk/group/west/pdf/Cunningham_etal14.pdf). [Slave-making ants raid and attack other ant species](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/14225/0). These intertribal conflicts seem to happen in nature due to in-group favoritism that causes certain creatures to favor members of their own phenotype when [it comes to companionship and territory defense](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4371377/).